# How long does it take until account unblocked

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

From few days ago I am blocked, I think the cause for indirect question by me(plus little hard worded), to now I earned some reputation but this doesn't release me.

Comment: In what way is your account blocked?

Comment: I can't ask question any more.

Comment: One of the following posts _may_ apply to you: [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/); [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4359/); [I apparently got question-banned for deleting some of my old, zero-upvoted questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91956/); [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/).

Comment: Hmm. I assume you have already read [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) - I guess you'll have to keep at it, and provide some more answers that get upvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no time limit for poor questions.  You can answer questions and get more reputation, or you can go back and fix the problems on your old questions and ask people to reevaluate them and upvote them.

If you need help fixing your old questions, post a message here indicating you really want to improve and ask for people to give you suggestions on specific ways to improve your questions.  I expect if you do a good job people here will be happy to provide the upvotes you need to continue asking questions.

Comment: My last question had been deleted, so I will take care more in future.

Comment: Is there a way to get help in having ban removed? Im afraid to ask this question because it would come as a duplicate. Is there a place to go to have site admins look at my account and give suggestions to lift ban?

Comment: Now I have 100 reputation but, it is still block for asking questions