# Does deleting any kind of post counts toward question-ban, and with the same intensity?

Tags: feature-request, support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should self-deletes be evaluated in the question ban algorithm?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103656/how-should-self-deletes-be-evaluated-in-the-question-ban-algorithm)

I know there are multiple factors that are used when banning a user, (deleting content is just one of many). But I am curious on how this is measured, for example:

- Is there any difference if you delete a post created *6 mins* ago compared with a *1 year* ago?
- "..." post with low visits v.s relatively high visits?
- "..." post with few comments v.s many of comments?
- "..." post with negative score v.s positive score?
- etc

Are these metrics used? (if not, I think they should)

I made this post primarily because I was able to answer a very basic silly not-worth-keeping-in-this-site question made by me, so I decided to delete it instead of answering it. And I thought:

> *"well, my question was alive for about 6 minutes only, with 14 visits and 0 comments, it would be a shame that this weighted the same than a X
>   hours ago + 5 clarifying comments question."*

After all, the reason behind frowning upon deleting is that you waste other user's time, and by using some of the questions above we can make a pretty good guess about how much time was wasted and we can adjust the intensity of the punishment (or lack of thereof) accordingly.

Comment: btw, my first thought was the opposite (the older the worse), but it starts to make more sense after reading about those abusive guys who delete and repost