# Do community and moderator deletes penalize in the same way that self-deletes do?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban, vote-to-delete

One of the few things we know about the automatic ban mechanism is that [it penalizes for *self*-deletes of content less than 30 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103670/135887).

While generously applying my daily quota of delete votes on *horrible* questions, it occurred to me that I might also be penalizing the user in some way.  I could understand why this would be a good thing, but it makes me slightly uneasy.

My understanding of the self-delete penalty is that it targets users that post bad content, delete it, then try reposting it.  If that's the real intent, then I wouldn't imagine that non-self-deletes would count in the same way.  On the other hand, if you post something so terrible that the community or a diamond-mod decide it's not even worth *keeping*, that's gotta count, right?

Thus the question: do community deletes and moderator deletes count towards the auto-ban mechanism in the same way that self-deletes do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

Well, not sure about the *exact* same way (there might be some weighting going on that I'm not aware of), but questions deleted by other users or moderators definitely count.

Comment: Thanks Anna!  This may lead me to be a bit more judicious in voting to delete.  Or not.