# Flagging a question as duplicate to a question of the same user(which gets deleted)

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I recently flagged a question as being a duplicate to another question, all posted by the same user ([current open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796108/dynamically-added-edittexts-and-forcing-the-user-to-enter-data-on-focus-change)). Now I've seen that the user, in response to my close flag and the

> possible duplicate...

comment, deleted the previous question. This renders my flag useless as there is no duplicate question anymore. How should I handle this(if an action is required)?

Now, I've searched a bit here on meta and mainly found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post) but the answer from `Shog9` doesn't seem to apply here as the question is valid(probably, I would say) and it should stay open. `Ether`'s answer from the question above represents a summary of the situation I explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Normally* I'd have starred the duplicate question after voting to close it as a dupe, to come back to it later and vote to delete the post. No point in having practically identical copies cluttering up the site.

Since the OP now has deleted the other post, the desired result has also been achieved: only *one* copy of the question exists. I *have* added a comment to the OP to tell him to next time just edit the original question instead of creating a new post.

As for the close vote, people will see the original has been deleted and ignore the close vote. It *could* be robo-voters close the post anyway, in which case the OP has only him- or herself to thank for that, and can request a re-open. If the post garners enough views (over 100) then the vote will automatically expire after 4 days, provided no other votes are added.

Comment: Right, but the OP has now successfully gamed the system. If necessary, they can rinse and repeat as many times as they want unless the question becomes undeleteable.

Comment: @Asad: "gamed the system"? No, he has added strikes against himself when it comes to the automatic question ban. Otherwise, if he had edited the old question it would have been bumped onto the homepage either way.

Comment: A heavily downvoted question, once edited, is unlikely to get anyone's attention. Making a new question gets you a clean slate. I didn't consider the question ban though, true enough.

Comment: @Asad well since [self-deletion penalizes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158390/165773 "as explained here"), this is not totally free for "gamer"

Comment: @gnat Yeah I know, Martin just pointed this out.

Comment: @Asad: The original question had received *no* votes whatsoever.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, in this specific case.

Comment: I understand, the question was more about the system leaving in this situation(in my opinion) "leftovers" which maybe should/could be avoided somehow.

Comment: If you try to VTC as a dupe of the indicated question, you get "No eligible question found at that url." I haven't tried to go further, so maybe the most ardent robo-close-voters could vote to close as dupe of a no-longer existing question, but it shold be safe from the average robo-voter.