# Handling a cross-posted Question

Tags: support, specific-question, cross-posting

I think this Question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17661547/1287812, is pure WordPress (involves core behavior, server configuration and maybe programming) and voted to close as such.

OP then posted the same Q at WordPress Answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106739/12615.

My doubt: suggest him to delete the Stack Overflow post or is it better to flag for a moderator to do it?

If the OP deleted the Q, would that fall under the Question Ban calculations?
If flagging is the preferred way, is there any difference if the OP flags or if another user does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the OP deleted the Q, would that fall under the Question Ban calculations?

Can't answer since I don't have access to the exact algorithm but my guess is that yes it would count.

> If flagging is the preferred way, is there any difference if the OP flags or if another user does?

No there is no differences. The only thing flagging does is getting the moderator's attention. The only differences is if you flag it and it gets migrated, you'll have a *+1 helpful flag*.

> My doubt: suggest him to delete the Stack Overflow post or is it better to flag for a moderator to do it?

Flag it. Moderators have the options to simply migrate it with the current content. Right now, there is no essential content but let say someone gave a useful answer it it would stay in place instead of being deleted if the OP deletes the post.

Comment: Your comment about OP versus someone else being the same is incorrect.

Comment: @corsiKa What is the difference then ?

Answer (score 1):

Op should delete it himself in 30 days if he wants to avoid hurting his question ban score.

According to [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103670/147335), if a user deletes his own post that is 30 days old, it will not count against his question ban algorithm score doohickey thingamabob.

That being said, this would really only matter if the user in question is dangerously close to being question banned anyway. If he isn't remotely close to being question banned, then he can easily afford to have a question deleted. If he is dangerously close to being question banned, and this does push him over, it's unfortunate for him but ultimately the system is working as intended.

As a third party observer, your best bet is to issue a moderator flag, or a delete vote if you can.