# After how many "closed" questions does an account forgo its privilege to ask questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

Is the number constant or does it change as the reputation of a user grows?

I've been there, myself, in the beginning, I had my privileges revoked. I don't want to repeat such a thing.

Can we list factors that contribute to it, then?

Comment: The algorithm to determine when users are question banned is intentionally not disclosed, but they have stated that a number of factors contribute; closed questions is just one.  Downvotes, deleted question, etc. also contribute.

Comment: bad flags as well

Comment: and if you delete your own question before 30 days, it counts toward your ban. Source: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103656/how-should-self-deletes-be-evaluated-in-the-question-ban-algorithm

Comment: @SamuelLiew: I've not seen anyone say that bad flags contributed to a post ban, only a flagging ban.

Comment: Generally if you can ask good questions you shouldn't even have to worry about how many of your questions get closed.

Comment: @AlEverett I meant approved mod/spam flags by others counting against the question

Comment: Its not easy to predict. I started learning programming. Its not easy to predict which will get upvoted or downvoted. Many questions start with downvotes and end with upvotes. In any case, i get the gist.

Comment: for example, i couldn't have predicted these downvotes for this question as well.

Comment: @SangramSingh: I suspect that the downvotes on this particular question are mostly because we see a lot of "how does the post-ban algorithm work" questions here. I think folks would have liked it better if you'd done a little research first.

Comment: @AlEverett fair enough.

Comment: All of the information you're going to get is already made available here: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)

Comment: [multiposting is not welcome here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197248/my-account-was-just-banned-from-asking-questions-how-do-i-find-why-what-about?noredirect=1#comment623890_197248)

Answer (score 9):

There's too many factors to even come up with an *average* number of questions, although the number of questions you've asked is taken into consideration. Basically, *everything* surrounding the questions you've asked is taken into consideration.

You could have 5, 10 or even 15 questions before it kicked in depending on how the questions were voted on, how many were deleted, and a whole lot of other things. We deliberately *do not* disclose the mechanics of the algorithm *because we don't want people doing the least amount needed to squeak by instead of just trying to write decent questions*.

The same goes for our quality filters that rejects questions not due to a block, but for poor formatting, capitalization, etc. We don't want to tell folks *exactly* what that looks for or we'll end up with a poor question that barely squeaked by, when the system is deliberately trying to get a better question altogether.

Just put effort into your questions and you should not have to worry about it. A neat trick is to read them *out loud* to yourself before you post them to make sure that they read well, and include everything you meant to say.

The rest is, well, seekrit.

Comment: Going further with the read aloud thing, try to imagine what your reaction would be if someone posted the question and you (without your personal knowledge about the situation) stumbled upon it.