# What could have triggered a question ban in this case?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban, policy, self-delete

I would like to know what triggers a question ban? Is it based on votes?

After self deleting a question on programmers, I got a question ban. What's the reason?

<sub>This question is submitted at MSO [per advice of Programmers moderator](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6599/why-do-i-get-questionblock-after-just-two-deleted-questions#comment17788_6600): "The only advice I could give is to consider posting on Meta Stack Overflow since the algorithm is used across the network. Is it weird that a self-deletion triggered it..."</sub>

Comment: But in summary;  downvotes, closures and deletions (including self deletions) are all bad

Comment: Asking a question that's been asked hundreds of times before triggers it.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The duplicate does not get suggested when using `What triggers a question ban?` as the question title. This place is supposed to be a support site.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193366/after-how-many-closed-questions-does-an-account-forgo-its-privilege-to-ask-que http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188291/will-asking-too-many-duplicate-questions-lead-to-a-question-ban http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74599/does-deleting-my-own-question-or-answer-attract-penalty/

Comment: @Pëkka the faq clearly says "To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities". As for downvotes, it's due to not taking the time to read that faq which is linked in the post ban message.

Comment: @Shadow at the time I posted my comment, there was no indication that the user actually was banned himself (I must have had it open for a while)

Comment: @Pëkka I am banned at programmers atm. And I was confused, why I got it just after one question, which I deleted myself.

Comment: @Knerd the one thing we do know is that a single question isn't enough. There must be something else

Comment: @RichardTingle Good to know, I gonna try to research it.

Comment: Knerd and @Richard - there is a chance someone sharing your IP got a ban, but if it happened right after you deleted a question I don't think it's a coincidence. More likely you asked something in the past, that got downvoted and deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, that happend, but how long do they last for?

Comment: @Knerd, essentially forever, for all we know.

Comment: @Knerd Until the conditions that caused then are no longer true, could be 5 minutes, could be the rest of time. This is why improving your existing questions (could the self deleted question be improved rather than deleted?)

Comment: I just re-checked, "What can I do..." duplicate seems to have a guidance covering your case: "if many of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted, closed, or **deleted by yourself** or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality. Be sure to understand why that happens, and learn from that..." => self-deletions are supposed to contribute to triggering ban

Comment: @RichardTingle the question was wrong on programmers, so I reasked on stackoverflow and deleted it ;)