# I have been banned from stack overflow - should I undelete my posts?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, post-ban

I was recently banned form stack overflow. Before I got banned, I would delete any post that was received negatively (I now know that was a very bad idea). **I am wondering if it would be better for me to undelete and edit my posts or would it be better if I just leave them deleted?** Also, is there any thing else that I could do to get un-banned faster (like answer question)?

Comment: The only way to remove your question ban is to improve your existing questions and your deleted questions.  You can also wait 6 months, at which time, you will be allowed to ask a single question proving you understand what's good question is.

Comment: but if the questions where already deleted when I got banned, should I undelete and edit them?

Comment: Yes, a single deleted question (or perhaps two) is neither her nor there but more than that if you are low rep is likely to put you well on the way to a ban staying.

Comment: Read my comment again. I provided you the only way to remove your question ban.  I have no idea how many questions you deleted.  Based on the fact nearly none of your questions have a positive score (most were 0) any question that is voted down significantly effects your ability to ask a question.  Only reason you had not been with question banned earlier is likely because of all your positively voted answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this was an auto-ban (not a suspension), then yes, you should undelete *and fix* your questions.  Downvotes, closures, self-deletions [within the first 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103670/162102), and community/moderator deletions (at any time, I think) all contribute toward the ban.  See the recommendations in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) about how to recover.