# Why hasn't the automatic ban lifted despite my efforts?

Tags: support, post-ban

I'm at a complete loss. I've got an auto-question ban, and I've done everything I can to get it removed. I have tried answering lots of questions, I have tried editing and deleting old posts which were of low quality, I've tried holding out until the posts aren't taken into account after deletion (30 days then delete then it doesn't count to the filter iirc). However, I still have a ban.

EDIT: Thank you! I'm now able to ask questions in Stack Overflow again. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: This is the first time I hear about the 30 days rule. Who told you that? Also, you have been posting answers, and it's clear (at least to me) that you've tried. Asking on Meta is perfectly reasonable at this point, imho.

Comment: With a +12 vote count on one of your answers, surely you cannot be far off.

Comment: Deleting old posts may well hinder rather than help your cause. Were these questions or answers?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but given the answers you received to [this heavily downvoted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423947/i-need-a-completely-invisible-button), you can surely come up with a better question which does not invalidate the answers. Perhaps even resulting in it being reopened? Just a hint though.

Comment: It was questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Yannis I read something at http://goo.gl/C1Kwu: Yes, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) and deleted answers count towards an automatic ban.

Comment: @ofstream Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @ofstream I've changed the phrasing of the linked question slightly from "I need" (which some might read as "give me teh codez") to "I want to create", which indicates some of your own effort. Perhaps that helps.

Comment: Congrats! Make sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [/about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page in order to prevent it to happen again.

Comment: I made sure to read those during my question ban :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't delete your old posts!

Even though posts older than 30 days are not taken into an account, *their down votes still are*. Flag any of your posts to moderator attention, tell him you want to improve your previous posts and ask him to undelete them for you.

Once the posts are undeleted, improve them enough for them to get upvotes and reopened.

Posting answers help too! So keep it up, you aren't far off.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, you can't be certain he isn't far off, for all you (and I) know, he might have 1K deleted questions (exaggerating to make a point).

Comment: Thanks :) It's really appreciated.

Comment: @Yannis: He has a +12 answer, he can't be *that* far off.

Comment: Highly depends on the deleted posts, a couple of -20 questions would probably negate that +12 answer.

Comment: @Yannis: Which (again) isn't very likely. I guess it depends on him though, improving his deleted questions is the way to go, answering will *help*.

Comment: The worst I have is (iirc) a -5 question, the one I have hesitated to delete.

Comment: You're wrong. Posts older than 30 days [are not taken into account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720), provided that they were self-deleted.

Comment: @lunboks: Amended.