# Can you get comment banned?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

I know you can get question banned by asking enough questions of low enough quality that you cannot continue to post.

I find myself flagging a lot of comments as spam or chatty from a few users on another Stack Exchange site.

Is there a similar mechanism for becoming "comment banned," based on enough of your comments being flagged by enough different users?

Comment: As this has been confirmed it doesn't exist, it would be nice to see this incorporated as a feature (perhaps auto comment *suspensions* first to act as warning)

Comment: Im glad there isnt as I myself often delete my own comments when they become no longer relevant. I did worry that in the same way that self deleted questions/answers can lead to a ban; self deleted comments might

Comment: @RichardTingle Self deleted questions will not _lead_ to a ban. Heavily downvoted questions will lead to a ban, and it won't make a difference if they are deleted or not. Also there's no comparison between deleted posts and deleted comments. Comments are supposed to be ephemeral, self deleting them is a good thing.

Comment: @Yannis This question suggests self deleted questiond do lead to a ban http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720

Comment: @RichardTingle Deleted questions _count_, sure. That's different than "lead to a ban". It's not the deletion that leads to the ban, it's that the questions have been downvoted and closed.

Comment: That link suggested they had lots of unanswered 0 vote questions. They deleted them, and then were banned

Answer (score 12):

There is no automated mechanism for being banned from posting comments, no.

Comment: Is there a manual mechanism for being comment banned that you know of?

Comment: @RhysW Well, you can't comment if you're suspended.  I don't know of any mechanism for being banned from just posting comments.  It wouldn't surprise me too much if it existed though.

Comment: No, suspension is the only recourse. And yes, it does happen.