# Have I been banned from posting comments?

Tags: support, comments

I have been trying to post my comments at MSE for the past few months since last year without any success. Every time I post a comment, there would be no feedback. Could it be that I have been banned from posting comments? If there is a way to get around this, please shed some light with me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Never heard of a comment ban. Have you tried different browsers? Does the browser console (F12 on Chrome and prob. others) show any errors?

Comment: If you did, I'd like to know how. There's a few users I know who could benefit froma comment suspension on my site ;p . SE certainly has no hellbans, so could it just be no one felt that they needed to respond to your comments.

Comment: No such thing. Something on your side is blocking/breaking required JavaScript, it can be some user script you installed long ago, and breaking stuff. Try with fresh clean browser, or disable all user scripts, plugins, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no such thing as a comment ban, independent of a suspension - see [Can you get comment banned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184451/can-you-get-comment-banned)

It looks like a selective comment ban has been proposed, but not implemented, at [Implement a Selective Comment Ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233916/implement-a-selective-comment-ban).