# Do not use `code formatting` for the number of days on the Roomba help center page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-formatting, help-center

On the [Help Center page about Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) (the script that automatically deletes 'abandoned' bad questions), code formatting is used a couple of times. While it's OK (at least in my book) to use this for the technical enumeration(?) values of the deletion reasons like `RemoveDeadQuestions`, it's not appropriate for the number of days, which are just a natural part of the sentence. Currently, they're [breaking the flow for users with screen readers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301372/295232).
It could be some attempt to indicate that these are variables, but they're not dynamically calculated when the page loads. On other pages with days 'variables', like the [bounty](/help/bounty) page, don't have this type of formatting either.

[image: part of the help center page]

Oh, and while you're at it, please format the second to last link (the one to [What should I do if I find the answer to an old question of mine that was automatically deleted as abandoned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309526/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-the-answer-to-an-old-question-of-mine-that-was-automa/310266#310266)).

Comment: That page needs to be re-written. I work here, I think I even fixed one of the queries to scope questions, and that  page makes my head spin.

Comment: I won't disagree with that, but at least it's understandable enough to build [userscripts](https://stackapps.com/q/7239/34061) based on it.

Comment: I have seen this suggested before but my search-fu is failing me. I can't find that previous post either here or in MSO. (Then again, it may have been deleted and I don't have enough rep to see deleted posts :-( ) I did find [this comment](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339077/#comment418593_339077) by Cody Gray, though.

Comment: TBH, I haven't checked for duplicates on MSO, only here.

Comment: I only mentioned MSO because it would have been the only other site where I would have seen this raised before.

Comment: I suggested that in a comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1012950).

Comment: @DonaldDuck right. I must've missed that question. It explains the current state of that page quite well :)

Comment: This proposed change (and [this one on MSO about adding the word "Roomba" to the body text for searchability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376734/1478931)) is easy enough to implement... If anyone thinks the page should be more substantially rewritten, please suggest how it should be rewritten in a separate feature request.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the [original post that was copied into the help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/377214) so it doesn't use code formatting either.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog ah, thanks, now I see it's all Jeff's fault :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated this Help Center page network-wide to remove the code formatting from these numbers.

I also removed the mentions of the specific deletion reasons used in the code (which used to be shown in the post notice on posts deleted for those reasons, but aren't shown there anymore).

In addition, I formatted the link in the last line, as you suggested.

(I also made these same changes to the translations of this Help Center page shown on our international SO sites.)

Comment: While those deletion reasons aren't shown in the post notices anymore, they *are* shown in post timelines.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Yep, I'm aware – and I think they are mentioned in the revision history as well. But I don't think it's useful to highlight those technical names from the code directly on this Help Center page itself.