# Link to help center instead of meta FAQ on community user profile for automatic question deletion

Tags: support, profile-page, community-user

On the Community user profile there is a list item *Remove abandoned questions*. This item links to [this](/a/92006) meta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), but should probably link to the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) article:

[image: Profile page from community and red free hand line on the list item]

The help center also includes a link to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309526/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-the-answer-to-an-old-question-of-mine-that-was-automa/310266#310266) explaining what to do when a question is deleted, which is more useful when you come from the deletion notice (having clicked on the user link).

Comment: The link to the meta FAQ is there for historical reasons, as the help pages were created *after* the link was added there. At that time, the meta FAQ was the only reference to this behavior.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog I know that it is for historical reasons. But I think a link to the help page would be better because it looks more official and it contains the one link I wrote of.