# Some links in Help Center articles are not being formatted

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center

There are a couple of Help Center articles with unformatted ('bare') links:

- [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) contains a link to an answer by Shog9: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309526/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-the-answer-to-an-old-question-of-mine-that-was-automa/310266#310266`
- [How to not be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) contains a link to a question by Shog9: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer`
- [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) contains `https://webapps.stackexchange.com` (not sure if that needs to be a link, as the other mentioned sites aren't linked to either - it could just be the words "Web Applications")
- There's another instance in the moderator-only Help Center article about moderator messages, near the bottom

Could they be formatted so that they are in line with the rest of the links in the articles?

Comment: ... I'm actually wondering whether we made a change recently that stripped out the "convert links to MSE into pretty links" on Help Center pages - I can certainly make them pretty but, as far as I'm aware, they *should* be doing it on their own, as any post linking to MSE would do.

Comment: @Catija it seems you're right: the link on the Roomba page *was* formatted back in 2018: http://web.archive.org/web/20180601133047/stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Answer (score 5):

If something broke, it seems to have been a hiccup in the system - re-saving the articles seems to have repaired the issue.

I'm not sure what happened to cause the problem but it seems to have fixed itself. If you find any more examples, I'll see if I can poke them or if it's a bigger issue.

Comment: You solved the first two instances; the other two are still there (or should I blame caching?)

Comment: The third one (webapps) seems to be intentional. It's not actually in markup at all, it's just written exactly like that with the bare URL... and we don't convert URLs like that. I'm kinda ambivalent about whether it should change? I fixed the last one now.